# how do I make my sort function working to actually display the sorted books in the tableview

Tags: swift, realm, dropdown

Hi tried to create a sort button with the CocoaPods Dropdown, the code doesn't show any error and the menu works, but if I click on the button nothing is happening.

```
    dropDown.selectionAction = { [weak self] (index: Int, item: String) in //8
      guard let _ = self else { return }
      sender.setTitle(item, for: .normal) //9
       
        let realm = try! Realm()
        var books = realm.objects(Book.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "title", ascending: false)
    
        if item == "sort by author" {
            func filterResultsbyauthor(searchString: String){
                 let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "author BEGINSWITH [c]%@", searchString)
                books = realm.objects(Book.self).filter(predicate).sorted(byKeyPath:"author", ascending: true)
                self?.tableview.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code is a bit hard to follow. Why are you reading books twice? Is 'books' your tableView datasource? If so it won't display anything because books is a local var `var books = realm.objects` - is that intentional? Also, why are defining another function within the if statement `func filterResultsbyauthor(` as it's not being called.

Comment: I deleted the local variable and changed the function into a chunk of code as suggested, it is still not working. I get the error "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid value', reason: 'Expected object of type string for property 'author' on object of type 'Book', but received: (null)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is probably here:

```
func filterResultsbyauthor(searchString: String){
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "author BEGINSWITH [c]%@", searchString)
    books = realm.objects(Book.self).filter(predicate).sorted(byKeyPath:"author", ascending: true)
    self?.tableview.reloadData()
}
```

You defined a function, but never called it.

You can either:

1. Call the function

```
func filterResultsbyauthor(searchString: String){
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "author BEGINSWITH [c]%@", searchString)
    books = realm.objects(Book.self).filter(predicate).sorted(byKeyPath:"author", ascending: true)
    self?.tableview.reloadData()
}

filterResultsbyauthor(searchString: "Your search string") /// here!
```

2. Remove the function declaration and just make it a chunk of code

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "author BEGINSWITH [c]%@", "Your search string")
books = realm.objects(Book.self).filter(predicate).sorted(byKeyPath:"author", ascending: true)
self?.tableview.reloadData()
```

Comment: also Sender.setTitle needs to be called from the main queue. And you can safely remove the guard statement on self, it's not actually doing anything. If self gets deallocated before you call self? the optional chain will stop from crashing.